# Implement Btree with multi-elements node java

Tags: java, b-tree

I'm trying to implement a Btree in Java with multi-elements node with fixed element in each node.I'm trying to make an insert method for the tree.

In my code, for example, each node will contain 3 elements and each element will point to 2 children node (left and right). It works similar to 2,3 tree but the number of elements in each node could be a lot bigger and each node has fixed length elements.
Basically, the middle element will get promote when a node split.
This image shows how the insert works:

[image]
This is my code, I'm writing to start making root node but I don't know how to make the tree bigger by reuse the insert and split methods.

```
public class BTree {
    private Node root = null;
    int maxElementInNode = 3;
    public class Node { 
        //each node contain 3 elements
        Element[] elements;
        Element leftParent;
        Element rightParent;
        public Node(){
        }
    }
    public class Element{
        int key;
        String rId;
        Node leftNode;
        Node rightNode;
        public Element(int key, String rId){
            this.key = key;
            this.rId = rId;

        }

    }
    //add new element to tree
    public void addElement(int key, String rId){
        //add element to root node
        if(root == null){
            root = new Node();
            if (root.elements.length < maxElementInNode){
                for(int i = 0; i<root.elements.length;i++){
                    if(root.elements[i] == null){
                        root.elements[i] = new Element(key, rId);
                        Arrays.sort(root.elements);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //need to split
            }else{
                root = new Node();
                split(root);
            }
        }

    }

    public void split(Node nodeToSplit){
        if(root.elements == null){
            //first element of root = median element of split node
            root.elements[0] = nodeToSplit.elements[(maxElementInNode+1)/2];
        }
        Element[] leftChildNode = new Element[maxElementInNode];
        Element[] rightChildNode = new Element[maxElementInNode];
        for(int i = 0; i< (maxElementInNode+1)/2;i++){
            leftChildNode[i] = nodeToSplit.elements[i];
        }
        Node left = new Node();
        left.rightParent = nodeToSplit.elements[(maxElementInNode+1)/2];
        left.elements = leftChildNode;
        for(int j = ((maxElementInNode+1)/2)+1; j< maxElementInNode;j++){
            int i = 0;
            rightChildNode[i] = nodeToSplit.elements[j];
            i++;
        }
        Node right = new Node();
        right.elements = rightChildNode;
        right.leftParent = nodeToSplit.elements[(maxElementInNode+1)/2];
    }

}
```

Comment: post a link to the image and I'll add it

Comment: I think there are some basic issues you need to address before adding functionality, like: `Node` fields (elements, leftParent, rightParent) are not used. You need to initialize them using a constructor or a setter. The same applies to `Element` (leftNode, rightNode). Also `addElement` allows adding only to null root.

Comment: Thanks, I just put the image, I'm not very good at Java, just did the introduction of Java course. I've searched some of the code on the internet but it doesn't help me much.

Comment: So take it one step at a time. Fix the code first before you add functionality/

Comment: Do you mean the files Element(leftNode, rightNode) are not necessary? Or you mean I need to add constructor?

Comment: I elaborated in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the comments, see the following modified `Element` class:

```
public class Element{

    //you need a way to initialize fields. For this use a constructor,
    //a setter, or both 
    private int key;
    private String rId;
    private Node leftNode;
    private Node rightNode;

    //if all fields are know when constructing the object, you can do it 
    //in the constructor 
    public Element(int key, String rId, Node leftNode, Node rightNode) {

        this.key = key;
        this.rId = rId;
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
    }

    public Element(int key, String rId){

        this.key = key;
        this.rId = rId;
    }

    //alternatively, or in addition, you can use setters to set fields,
    //and getters to retrieve thier values (remove unneeded setters / getters)
    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getrId() {
        return rId;
    }

    public Node getLeftNode() {
        return leftNode;
    }

    public Node getRightNode() {
        return rightNode;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public void setrId(String rId) {
        this.rId = rId;
    }

    public void setLeftNode(Node leftNode) {
        this.leftNode = leftNode;
    }

    public void setRightNode(Node rightNode) {
        this.rightNode = rightNode;
    }
}
```

The same applies to `Node` class. 

 Also note the add `addElement` will do nothing when root is not null:

```
 public void addElement(int key, String rId){
        //add element to root node
        if(root == null){

        }
        //what  happens if root != null  ? 
  }
```